# why data is not accessible after returning Data from factory

Tags: angularjs

After returning data from factory, I tried to assign these with $scope.dummyTask. After assigning I can show these in console within callback function. But out side the function block , $scope.dummyTask is undefined, but why?

```
$scope.dummyTasks=[];    
$scope.getTask=function(){
Task.query(function(data){
$scope.dummyTasks=data;
console.log(angular.toJson($scope.dummyTasks));//shows desired data
});
};

$scope.getTask();   
console.log(angular.toJson($scope.dummyTasks));// shows undefined
```

Comment: What kind of object is `data` when returned from your query? Is it really an array?

Comment: JSON formated Data
[{"id":1,"task":"Break Fast","task_at":"2015-10-10 10:20:20","user_id":1,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"2015-10-10 08:44:33","status":"done","alarm":"0"},{"id":8,"task":"Dating With Poly","task_at":"2015-10-19 10:10:00","user_id":1,"created_at":"2015-10-09 20:40:23","updated_at":"2015-10-19 05:56:05","status":"done","alarm":"1"},{"id":9,"task":"Playing Football in the ground","task_at":"2015-10-21 17:05:00","user_id":1,"created_at":"2015-10-09 20:47:07","updated_at":"2015-10-09 20:47:07","status":"pending","alarm":"1"}]

Comment: So you need to do: `$scope.dummTasks = angular.fromJson(data)` to deserialize the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It shows undefined because `Task.query()` makes an **asynchronous** query.

It most probably sends a http request, and only when the response is available, the callback function is called, and `$scope.dummyTasks` is initialized.

```
// T0. send a query
Task.query(function(data) {

    // T2 (long after T1). initialize dummyTasks from the asynchronous response
    $scope.dummyTasks = data;
    console.log(angular.toJson($scope.dummyTasks));//shows desired data

});

// T1 (immediately after T0). display $scope.dummyTasks
console.log(angular.toJson($scope.dummyTasks));// shows undefined
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well. But as he initializes `$scope.dummyTasks=[];`, why is it 'undefined' immediatly after that?

Comment: My guess is that it's not showing undefined. Or it was, and the OP tried fixing it by initializing the variable with an empty array.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JB Nizet. Would please tell me the way how can I over come this situation? Can $q.deffer() help me at this fact? Or any thing else?

Comment: You just have to accept the fact that every IO in JavaScript is asynchronous. If you need to access the downloaded JSON, do it from the callback function.